# How to rotate an image given in base64 format in javascript in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

Suppose I have an image in base 64 format like so:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVbOSDFJsadFH234...
```

and I want to get the base64 string of the image rotated by say 90 degrees. How would I do that?

The suggested links use html/canvas. Is there a way to do it with pure javascript?

Comment: @Xaqron, using the first answer from your link gives me: "'callback' couldn't be found"

Comment: Then try other high-vote answers or leave a comment under problematic answer.

Comment: @Xaqron. I've edited the question, whose scope is different from your link. I would like to do it without any html components

Comment: Change your question. Base64 is nothing, it's just string data, any binary data can be trivially turned into, and converted from, base64 using Nodejs so we can ignore that: it's not relevant to your problem. The real question is "how do I rotate an image in Node", to which the answer is "by using any of quite a few image libraries that are easily found on npmjs.com". If those need "flies", then you write your data to file and unlink when done, but almost all know how to work with Buffer, because that's Node's favourite binary datastructure.

Comment: If you need to do this in back-end then first [convert base64 to buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img), rotate the image and convert the buffer to base64 again.